# Microsoft.Win32 could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winapi, using

I have a project which uses the following line of code to give users the option to select file locations etc.

```
Win32.SaveFileDialog dialog = new Win32.SaveFileDialog();
```

Using this however I get the following error:

```
the type or namespace name 'Win32' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I'm using the following "using directives" at the top of the file:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32;
```

I believe those are all that are required (actually, `using Microsoft.Win32` is probably not even required).

I've got the following project/assembly(?) references:

- Microsoft.CSharp
- Microsoft.Kinect
- PresentationCore
- PresentationFramework
- System
- System.Core
- System.Data
- System.Data.DataSetExtensions
- System.Xaml
- System.Xml
- System.Xml.Linq
- WindowsBase

I know there are a million questions around with these kind of problems but non of them seemed to help me out. I tried rebuilding the solution, cleaning it, closing and opening VS (2013). Unfortunately I'm not very well known with VS or C#, but I'd like to think that I tried most of the reasonable solutions out there.

Comment: Since your using Microsoft.Win32 and trying to use the Win32 directly I believe you also need to add the using Microsoft; directive to have access directly to Win32.

Comment: @deathismyfriend your suggestion didn't actually work, but since you mentioned "using it directly" it lead me to using `Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog`. It doesn't really matter to me if I use `Win32` or `Microsoft.Win32`, so thanks! :) Don't know why I didn't think of that before... Still weird it doesn't want to just use `Win32` though.

Comment: no problem did this fix it for you then ? Some of them don't work because the name ends up conflicting I believe. I had same problem before with windows forms and something else and that same error showed up.

Comment: @deathismyfriend Yeah that fixed it (using `Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog` directly).

Comment: that is good not sure if you want to write your own answer or let me write one to accept since mine wasn't the exact answer ?

Comment: @deathismyfriend Go ahead ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your using `Microsoft.Win32` and trying to use the `Win32` directly, I believe you also need to add the following directive to have access directly to `Win32`:

```
using Microsoft;
```

You instead needed this directive.

```
using Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog;
```

Or can use the following line of code for the same functionality:

```
Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dialog = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
```

Comment: Thanks, I opted for `Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dialog = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();`. It doesn't really matter to me if I use it directly a certain way or not ;)

Answer (score 7):

Remove and add again `PresentationFramework.dll` reference in your project.

> Namespace:  Microsoft.Win32 
>  Assembly:  PresentationFramework (in
>   PresentationFramework.dll)

[MSDN link to SaveFileDialog Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.savefiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Represents a common dialog that allows the user to specify a filename
>   to save a file as. SaveFileDialog cannot be used by an application
>   that is executing under partial trust.

Answer (score 0):

Use namespace `System.Windows.Forms` to use the functionality of `SaveFileDialog`.

Comment: There are multiple SaveFileDialog. Bono is trying to use the one in Microsoft directive not the one in windows forms.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with an old code I was re-editing in VS2015.

I just removed the `Microsoft.Win32` and left just `SaveFileDialog` (in both lines: directive and object creation) and it worked for me.